# Why does Linux kernel driver sr.c sr_block_ioctl do mutex_lock?

Tags: drivers

My PC has two Optical Disc Drives (ODDs). 
I burn file (3.8 G) to two ODDs at the same time.

- On CentOS 6.9 Linux Kernel 2.6.32, it takes about 10 minutes
- On CentOS 7.2 Linux Kernel 3.10.0, it takes about 16 minutes

I checked the system log and found that only one command can be running at the same time. 

That means send ATAPI commands to ODD1 and ODD2 at the same time. 
They are not executed in parallel.

I checked Linux Kernel Drivers `sr.c sr_block_ioctl()`.

[They added `mutex_lock` at Linux kernel 2.6.36.](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2a48fc0ab24241755dc93bfd4f01d68efab47f5a#diff-fea3c59f67a681059974f90a613be230)

I found this makes ATAPI commands not execute in parallel. 
I added debug log to dump the `&sr_mutex`, and I found the two ODDs use the same mutex key...`sr_mutex` is a global variable in `sr.c` (static DEFINE_MUTEX(sr_mutex);) 
On the other hand, I found `sd.c` does not use a lock at `ioctl` in Linux kernel last version...

Questions:

1. Why do the two ODD driver use the same global variable?
2. Why add `mutex_lock` here? ODD may need 2~3 seconds to complete a command.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

I have found this patch: [[PATCH] [SCSI] sr: Fix multi-drive performance by using per-device mutexes](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-scsi/msg63706.html)

Apply this patch, maybe the issue will be closed.